# CSS3 Div Animation Relative Spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently I have asked a similar question about transition animation in divs. ([See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407337/css3-animations-slide-in-div/41407505?noredirect=1#comment70038442_41407505))

The Code Snippet below shows my solution.
**However, the animation only works if the width is given in pixels, not as a percentage**.
Does anybody know a way around this?

EDIT (More info to clarify my problem):

In this section of a website, I have a heading that should always stay the same and 3 pages of content which can be "swiped" on user input.
Thus, the span of the left margin of the page would range from -100% to +100%.

I want a swiping animation so that the user can switch from page 2 (i.e. displaying an image) to page 3 (i.e. the text correlating to the image).

Because of different browser window sizes, I need the width to be in percentages. Sadly...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    var current = $(".container").css("left");
    if (current == "-200px") {
      current = "-400px";
    } else if (current == "0px") {
      current = "-200px";
    }
    $(".container").css("left", current);
  });
  $(".prev").click(function() {
    var current = $(".container").css("left");
    if (current == "-200px") {
      current = "0px";
    } else if (current == "-400px") {
      current = "-200px";
    }
    $(".container").css("left", current);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.ins {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Thanks to kittyCat at stackoverflow.com for helping me with this website.-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <meta name="Title" content="Main">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ins div1">div-1</div>
      <div class="ins div2">div-2</div>
      <div class="ins div3">div-3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="next">next</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are the percentage values which should be substituted for `px` units?

Comment: 100% (I want it to fill the full browser window) in width and somewhere around 80% in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the left positioning for a transform on the individual elements:

Now, also, the class row is set to occupy full browser width. The container class is se to 300% (because it will make room for 3 elements). And the children are set to 33% of this, that at the end is 100% of the row.

```js
var pos = 2; /* values 1 - 2 or 3 */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    if (pos == 1) {
      $(".container").removeClass("pos1");
      $(".container").addClass("pos2");
      pos++;
     } else if (pos == 2) {
      $(".container").removeClass("pos2");
      $(".container").addClass("pos3");
      pos++;
     }
  });
  $(".prev").click(function() {
    if (pos == 3) {
      $(".container").removeClass("pos3");
      $(".container").addClass("pos2");
      pos--;
     } else  if (pos == 2) {
      $(".container").removeClass("pos2");
      $(".container").addClass("pos1");
      pos--;
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.ins {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.pos2 .ins {
 transform: translateX(-100%);  
}
.pos3 .ins {
 transform: translateX(-200%);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Thanks to kittyCat at stackoverflow.com for helping me with this website.-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <meta name="Title" content="Main">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="container pos2">
      <div class="ins div1">div-1</div>
      <div class="ins div2">div-2</div>
      <div class="ins div3">div-3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="next">next</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not entirely what I'm looking for (at least I can't see a way to make it work the way described in the edit). But thanks so much for helping me anyways! I have edited my question with further information so that my problem and goal becomes clearer.

Comment: I have changed some widths. Luckily, most of the layout can stay the same.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Narusan,

If I'm understanding your goal correctly, part of the problem is that no matter what, jQuery wants to return px units to you.  You can set a percentage value, but it seems it will not then return those percentages to you.

I changed your code some to demonstrate this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    var current = $(".container").css("left");
    console.log(current);
    if (current == "-200px" || current == "-100%") {
      current = "-200%";
    } else if (current == "0%") {
      current = "-100%";
    }
    $(".container").css("left", current);
  });
  $(".prev").click(function() {
    var current = $(".container").css("left");
    console.log(current);

    if (current == "-200px" || current == "-100%") {
      current = "0%";
    } else if (current == "-200%") {
      current = "-100%";
    }
    $(".container").css("left", current);
  });
});
```

You'll see that the values printed to the console are always in px, but if you inspect the DOM you'll see that the % value is being set on the element.

Approaching the problem very differently, like vals did, seems like a good approach.

Comment: Sorry, I had to state my goal more clearly. I have edited my question and I hope it is easier to understand now. Thank you for your help!